# Amazons EC2 container service - are tasks deployed as docker containers inside docker containers?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

I have been reading [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/Welcome.html) overview on Amazon's EC2 container service. One thing that is confusing me is how tasks are deployed onto an EC2 cluster. Assume a task definition contains 2 container instances, 1 for wordpress and 1 for mysql. The following diagram shows an overview of the setup:

[image]

This shows the 2 tasks in a container instance. Is the container instance simply an EC2 VM? Or is it a docker container running on an EC2 instance?
Further, the 2 tasks here are docker containers as well and they run on a docker container?

The source of the confusion arises from another diagram further on in the overview, as shown below:

[image]

In this case, they are referred to as 'Cluster instances'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [container instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_instances.html) is an EC2 instance that is running the ECS agent.  You can launch the [ECS-optimized AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html) for a preconfigured system, or you can [use your own AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container_instance_AMIs.html) if you prefer.

Tasks are one or more containers deployed together.  Tasks are defined with [task definitions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definitions.html).  Tasks are not deployed as containers-inside-containers (Docker-in-Docker), but are just sets of containers running on your container instance.

The "cluster instances" term looks to be a typo.  I've reached out to our doc writers to get that corrected.

Comment: I think that the term "Cluster instances" is ok because is referring to "Instances that belong to the cluster"; although it could sound confusing to someone.

Comment: The diagram has been fixed to say "container instances".